# For sudo su - to retain SUDO_* environment variables?

Tags: environment-variables, sudo

We have a number of script (for Openstack operations) which require privileged execution in our environment.  For some of the scripts we'd like to refer back to the USERNAME or UID of the person who initiated the *sudo* session.

*sudo* already presents us with **SUDO_UID**, **SUDO_USER** environment settings.  This also works fine when using *sudo -s* to start a shell session.  However, if I use *sudo -i* or *sudo su -* then these settings are scrubbed from the environment.

Is there anything I can put into the */etc/sudoers* or */etc/sudo.conf* (perhaps even a "PLUGIN") which can allow me to start an interactive shell via *sudo* with root's environment initialized but ALSO with these specific SUDO_* settings preserved?

Comment: I hope it's clear that we're not concerned about hostile users getting access to the *sudo* authorized commands in this environment.  The use of *sudo* here is merely intended to minimize the time that our operations staff are exposed the root prompt where any finger fumbling can have dire consequences.

The idea is to have convenient access to a fully initialized root shell while also allowing relatively convenient access to various remote authenticated services under various ops team member names.

Comment: Have you looked at the various `env_*` settings for `/etc/sudoers`?

Comment: Adding this line: Defaults    env_keep += "SUDO_USER SUDO_UID SUDO_COMMAND" does resolve the issue for sudo -i ... but doesn't seem to help for sudo su -; I'm going to guess that nothing short of a patch to the su command would solve that latter issue.